# Html too narrow when creating new html Evernote note with AppleScript

Tags: html, applescript, evernote

I'm creating new notes in Evernote with a simple AppleScript. The core of the script is

> property theContent: ""
>
> set theNote to create note with html theContent

I populate the property theContent with different hmtl documents and write those to Evernote. For most documents this works fine. However, for some html the result is odd: [Evernote note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwRJb.png). The html itself is fine:[original html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YdSG.png) . I've uploaded the html to [original html](https://www.mothsoftware.com/downloads/bucket.html).

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this behavior?